# Go for tuition (extra classes) (private tutor)

Tags: word-usage, american-english, spoken-english

This question is about the use of "tuition" in AmE.

In America are there "private institutions" [not schools, universities]. So will it be okay to use:

> I go for tuition .

What about:

> A:"Where do you go for tuitions?"
>
> > B: "I go for tuition to X." ("I go to X to get tuition in a particular subject", that is, "I go to X for extra classes)
>
> I am taking tuition in Science. (I am teaching students Science)
>
> I receive (or "being given") tuition in Science. (I have been taking extra classes in Science)

All these are private classes by tutors teaching a group of kids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*tuition* refers to payment for school in American English. You pay tuition. The word you want to use here is *tutoring* (or similar/related forms):

> I go for tutoring in science.
>
> I get tutoring in science.
>
> I get science tutoring.
>
> I get tutored in science.
>
> I am tutored in science.
>
> I receive science tutoring.
>
> I have a science tutor.

Comment: It's true that unqualified ***tuition*** is sometimes used to mean ***tuition fees / costs / charges***, but that doesn't mean it can't directly replace ***tutoring*** in all your examples. And not all tuition is explicitly paid for anyway.

Comment: And Mixolydian, will "tutoring" be used in America? I mean is this practice of "tutoring" common in America?

Comment: The person who "tutors" is a tutor. And if you "go for tutoring" can it mean both "teaching a kid" and "get tutored by a tutor" in different contexts, right?

Comment: @FumbleFingers and It’sAboutEnglish - American here- I would only use *tuition* to mean “school fees/costs/charges” but it is certainly possible that other people would also use *tuition* to describe what I would call *tutoring*. I agree that it is not always paid for - you can have “free tuition” if there is no cost to you.

Comment: @It’sAboutEnglish yes, from my experience in America, “tutoring” is the act of teaching someone outside of normal school time- usually one-on-one but not always. The person who tutors is a tutor. If you “go for tutoring” to me that can only mean “get tutored by a tutor.”

Comment: Is this practice of "tutoring" common in America?

Comment: @It’sAboutEnglish - yes, tutoring is common in America. I see you’re talking about a private class for a group of kids- that would probably still be called “tutoring”- it doesn’t have to be one-on-one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think i have ever seen or heard "tuition" used to mean "teaching" as opposed to "fees for teaching" in US English, although i have read it many times in texts from the UK, and i think Canada. In addition to "tutoring" the phrase "giving private lessons" is used, most often in the context of music or art lessons. When the tutor is highly skilled and reputed, "giving a master class" is a common phrase.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: Well, if you're telling me this is a US/UK usage split (With Canada sticking up for the UK) then I can't really argue. Certainly Google NGrams seems to be telling me that there's a big difference between the relative prevalence of ***pay tuition / pay for tuition*** between US and UK corpuses.

Comment: ...and GB tells me that whereas ***pay for tuition*** and ***pay for tutoring*** are about equally common in the AmE corpus, in BrE the ***tutoring*** version is too uncommon to even show at all on a usage chart.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes i think this is a difference in US/UK usage. I suspect that the instances of "pay for tuition" in th3e US corpus are still largely using 'tuition" to mean "charges for teaching" and not 'teaching", but I might be mistaken there. Unfortunately, Google Ngrams can't be set to a **semantic** filter that returns only a particular **sense** of a word -- nor can any AI, yet, as far as i know.

Comment: And is it common to use: "I go for tutoring to X"

Comment: @It’sAboutEnglish not worded that way - the “to” part should come before the “for” part: “I go to X for tutoring.”

Comment: And @Mixolydian , will it sound like "I go to institution X for tutoring" or will it sound like "I visit X for tutoring" [as in a person],  I want it to mean X.

Comment: I am not sure what you want X to be but in the sentence “I go to X for tutoring” X can be either an institution or a person.

Comment: And in America what are they called: "tutoring institutions" or "tutoring centers"?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish "tutoring centers" sounds like a good phrase - "tutoring institutions" does not sound quite right.  "test preparation centers" could be used if they are meant to prepare students for a specific test.

Comment: So the setence can be: "He goes to X tutoring center for tutoring."

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish sure, that works, if "X tutoring center" is the name of a tutoring center. If the name is just X, then you don't need to include "tutoring center" too.